# Get name of variable that was used to pass param

Tags: ruby

Is there a way for a method to know the name of the variable in the caller that was passed as a param into the method?

Real world use case scenario: I use a homegrown tool that simply outputs strings to a file. It's nothing fancy but it suits my purposes. So, for example, I might want to output a simple string:

```rb
MYTOOL.puts 'some useful information'
```

I frequently want to output the name and value of a variable. I find myself doing this a lot:

```rb
MYTOOL.puts 'variable: ' + variable
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```rb
MYTOOL.showvar variable
```

Back in my Perl days I was able to use a preprocessor so that I could do this:

```perl
showvar $variable;
```

I'd rather avoid using a preprocessor, though. Is there a way to do this sort of thing in Ruby?

EDIT: I'm using the following version of Ruby:

ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: Only need it for local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the shorted syntax to pass keyword arguments which was introduced in Ruby 3.1, e.g. as follows

```
variable = "hello world"
puts variable:
# => {:variable=>"hello world"}
```

This is equivalent to calling

```
puts variable: variable
```

This feature to Ruby was introduced with [#14579](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14579) and released with Ruby 3.1.

For older Rubies, you have to be a bit more creative. One possibility would be to leverage the [binding_of_caller](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) gem which allows us to access the [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Binding.html) of the code which calls our debug method. This allows us to access local variables set in this context.

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

class MyTool
  def showvar(*variables)
    caller_binding = binding.of_caller(1)
    variables.each do |var|
      puts "#{var}: #{caller_binding.local_variable_get(var.to_sym).inspect}"
    end
  end
end

MYTOOL = MyTool.new

hello = "hello world"
MYTOOL.showvar(:hello)
# => hello: "hello world"
```

Note that unwinding the stack to access the binding is quite expensive in Ruby. As such, if you use this a lot, your code may become rather slow. It's probably fine for some limited debugging though.

Comment: That's just nothing but cool. Unfortunately, using version 2.7. But I'll watch for this. Thanks!